# Jquery etc to move blocks of content using the mouse?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web

So essentially I have blocks of text on a page, essentially just about 10 same sizes boxes of text using CSS. I want to be able to order these though - and so drag and drop one. I can code the backend ordering myself - can anyone recommend where to go for the fronnt-end drag and drop? I'm aware that jquery would probably be my best bet, yet I've never used javascript so if there's any sort of code already created for this then that'd be incredibly helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+drag+and+drop&oq=jquery+drag+and+drop

Comment: I agree that Googling before posting the question is very much in order, but note that I've tried most of the libraries out there and they are all pretty limited. (We ended up writing our own library for this, which I'd cheerfully post but it's not open source (yet).) If you can assume modern browsers, the HTML5 built-in drag functionality is better than the libraries I've seen (albeit a little convoluted to work with).

Answer (score 0):

You mean this? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

Here's jQueryUI's draggable and droppable:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

They're kind kind of cute but might well not do what you want.

Here's a pretty straightforward explanation of how to implement drag and drop the HTML5 way:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

(It mostly convinced me to implement my own rather than wait for better HTML5 drag and drop support.)

Here's an example for older browsers:

http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx

There's also draggable.js (and its jQuery port) neither of which I recommend.

Stuff these examples don't really do includes pretty much anything useful. E.g. what if you want to target PARTS of an object or the spaces BETWEEN objects? How can you make targets dynamics based on what's going on in the page. It all gets very ugly very fast.

Sorry not to have a simpler answer.